# Semantic Versioning & Continuous Deployment

Tags: node.js, bower, continuous-deployment, semantic-versioning

Murphy kicked my a$$ about an hour ago.

[image]

### Context:

I recently joined a new employer and the product was quite outdated in terms of dependencies, `Angular 1.2.x`, `Angular-UI 0.12.0`, etc...

This is the first employer I've worked at that does daily builds to prod etc. (previosuly I've only worked in what can be called large corporate, with much slower turn around) Part of my initial task was to upgrade dependencies where I can. Thus earlier this morning we had a watercooler talk with some of the devs about why all of our bower dependencies are hardcoded to specific versions.

The 2 schools of thought are:

- Hardcoding versions obviously gives 100% security as versions can't dynamically jump, but has the drawback that if someone doesnt actively update we'll fall behind again.
- I'm of the opinion that semantic versioning gives us some form of security (coupled with having multiple staging environments), and that it should be good enough to, say, have Angular set to say `^1.5.9`.

**Quoted from the Semantic Version Docs:**

> Minor version Y (x.Y.z | x > 0) MUST be incremented if new, backwards
>   compatible functionality is introduced to the public API. It MUST be
>   incremented if any public API functionality is marked as deprecated.
>   It MAY be incremented if substantial new functionality or improvements
>   are introduced within the private code. It MAY include patch level
>   changes. Patch version MUST be reset to 0 when minor version is
>   incremented.

### Problem:

Earlier this morning we deployed to staging, and everything seemed good to go, then we deployed to production an hour or so ago and ... BOOM

The issue was the AngularJs change from `1.5.9`, to `1.6.0`. I've seen in the migration docs ([migrate 1.5 -> 1.6](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrate1.5to1.6-ng-services-$http)) that this has been noted:

> You may also notice that this release comes with a longer-than-usual
>   list of breaking changes. Don't let this dishearten you though, since
>   most of them are pretty minor - often not expected to affect real
>   applications. These breaking changes were necessary in order to:

### Question:

Where is my disconnect? ...or is the semantic version docs just a false sense of security I've had all along?

How do people out there in the handle these situations? Do people make use of auto dependency upgrading in any real world solutions (excuse me if this is super obvious to some), as to me, the fact that the build passed staging, and broke in production is actually more concerning.

*(The reason I'm asking is because the fear of small incremental updates are now back and stronger than ever, and I'm not sure if I agree with the sentiment of it all...)*

Comment: Prior to version 2 Angular did not follow semantic versioning. See https://angularjs.blogspot.co.za/2016/10/versioning-and-releasing-angular.html.

Comment: @Brett... I guess I have to learn from this yet again that assumption is the mother of all problems. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems pretty simple, if they make breaking changes, they should have bumped it up to 2.0.0.  They are not doing semantic versioning.  Not all projects using X.Y.Z. style versions are doing semantic versioning.

Try to catch how this went "boom" in an automated way in your testing and staging environments.  Can't fear moving forward, it has to be done sometime, and I'd rather move step-by-step more frequently, than to suddendly move up many versions as would be done with an entirely manual process.

Comment: To add to this, don't do automatic package upgrades during a production deploy. You always want to deploy EXACTLY what was tested. If I'm misunderstanding your situation and you did deploy what was tested, then you need better tests.